# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]

Tags: spring, web-services, cxf

I need to integrate Spring with CXF version 3.0. CXF libraries are in the classpath. I am getting the error "Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]" when trying to access the web service. What could be the wrong here ? By any chance Schema url got changed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you put the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws.jar into the class path?
The offline xml schema can be found there.

Comment: For google searches coming here, here's the maven link http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws